# BaseTokenFilterFactory not found by Solr with custom filter

Tags: java, lucene, solr, sunspot

I'm trying to write and use a custom filter for Solr. The parent application is a Rails app using the Sunspot gem.

I've got a filter factory in `myorg/solr/analysis/TestThingFilterFactory.java`:

```
package myorg.solr.analysis;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.solr.analysis.BaseTokenFilterFactory;
import myorg.solr.analysis.TestThingFilter;

public class TestThingFilterFactory extends BaseTokenFilterFactory {
  public TestThingFilter create(TokenStream input) {
    return new TestThingFilter(input);
  }
}
```

and a filter in `myorg/solr/analysis/TestThingFilter.java`:

```
package myorg.solr.analysis;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Token;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;

public class TestThingFilter extends TokenFilter {
  public TestThingFilter(TokenStream input) {
    super(input);
  }

  public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I compiled these files with `javac -classpath apache-solr-core-3.2.0.jar:lucene-core-3.2.0.jar myorg/solr/analysis/*.java`, then made a `.jar` file from the `.class` files and put the `.jar` file in Sunspot's `solr/lib/` directory. I modified Solr's `schema.xml` to include the new filter:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="myorg.solr.analysis.TestThingFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Restarting Solr and trying to reindex produces this error in the logs:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/analysis/BaseTokenFilterFactory
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.analysis.BaseTokenFilterFactory
...
```

This is a problem with how I compiled the new filter code, right? How do I compile so it can find the right classes at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: the new `.jar` file containing the custom analysis code should go in the `solr/lib/` directory *in the Rails root directory*, not within the vendored Sunspot gem. This is the same `solr/` directory that houses the `conf/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post about creating a [Solr Analysis Filter](http://java.dzone.com/news/writing-solr-analysis-filter) you need to also include the `lucene-core-3.2.0.jar` file in your classpath. I believe this is where the class `BaseTokenFilterFactory` is defined.

I found the lucene-core jar file [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/3.2.0/) if you need it...

Comment: I did include that file in the classpath, appended with a colon after the `apache-solr-core-3.2.0.jar` file. It wouldn't have compiled at all otherwise.